# Fetching JSON objects from multiple files based on offset and limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

In short, I would like to be able to create a JSON object from multiple JSON files while controlling the offset and limit of my search.

Each JSON file is named like `file-xxx.json`, where `xxx` represents the file's number. Each file can contain items up to a certain limit, defined by a variable (eg. `const maxItemsPerJSONFile = 10`). The main goal is to avoid fetching all JSON files and look through each of them individually instead of fetching just the required ones

Here is how each JSON file looks like:

```
[
    {
        "item": "value",
        "item": "value",
        etc...
    },
    {
        "item": "value",
        "item": "value",
        etc...
    },
    {
        "item": "value",
        "item": "value",
        etc...
    },
    etc...
]
```

I am struggling to come up with an algorithm that would allow me to fetch a specific range of items (by an item, I mean everything enclosed between the top-level curly brackets in each JSON file) from the collection of such files, based on an offset and a limit parameter.

Here is a basic outline of what I expect the code to look like:

```
function searchJSONFiles(offset, limit){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let finalResults = [];
        function main(){
            // Calculate "fileNumber"
            // ...

            $.ajax({
                url: `/directory/file-${fileNumber}.json`,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(response){
                    if(/* There are more files to be fetched, based on the limit */){
                        // Push current results from "response" to "finalResults" while respecting the offset
                        // ...

                        // Recalculate offset and limit and execute the main function again
                        // ...
                        main();
                    } else {
                        // Push final results from "response" to "finalResults" while respecting the offset
                        // ...

                        // Resolve and return the results
                        resolve(finalResults);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: So if you have `file-000.json` through to `file-999.json` you just want to check through e.g. `file-234.json` through `file-289.json` ? How would you know those indices ?

Comment: This sounds like a complicated way to redesign a key/value store.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie The point is not about knowing the indexes but about sparing the client from having to fetch too much data and comb through it.

Comment: @pilchard I know, but what I would like to avoid is for the client to download one huge file and look through every single record. This way, the client would only download the JSON files that contain the requested range of data.

Comment: @Looky1173 - if you know those indices you can generate the list in advance and look at `Promise.all` to retrieve those files.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie That's a good idea! However, how could I retain the order of the data, then?

Comment: @Looky1173 - can you update your question with more information about the order of the data ?